# Text in number input not vertically centering?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a number input with nice big fonts, but the text is not centered: http://snag.gy/HrICe.jpg

If I make the size of the font half of what it is, it centers fine, but it looks too small, particularly on mobile devices, and I cannot make the container any bigger due to the rest of the layout.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <style>
         .heightInput{
         color:#000;
         width:100%;
         height:100%;
         -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
         -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
         font-size: 34pt; 
         text-align: center;
         font-family: serif;
         border: 5px solid #000;
         }
      </style>
      <div style="width: 115px; height: 47px;" >
         <input type="number" name="InputA" id="InputA" min="14" max="24" step="1" value="18" class="heightInput">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

How can I get the text to keep the same size but appear centered vertically?

Answer (score 1):

You should try giving the same line-height as your height like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
  <style>
     .heightInput{
     color:#000;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     font-size: 34pt; 
     text-align: center;
     font-family: serif;
     border: 5px solid #000;
     line-height: 47px;
     }
  </style>
  <div style="width: 115px; height: 47px;" >
     <input type="number" name="InputA" id="InputA" min="14" max="24" step="1" value="18" class="heightInput">
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the line-height = font-size?  34px

Comment: Nope, her div has a 47px height, her input has a 100% height, if she wants to get her text vertically centered, she has to give the same line-height as her height. You can reproduce this behavior in all html tags, all you have to do is add vertical-align;middle along with the line-height setting.

Comment: I did reproduce this, that's why I asked.  With line-height set to 47 the text is still a little below center.  When I set it to 34 it centered exactly. YMMV

Comment: Yeah, you need to account for the border width as well.  So the actual line-height for this example should be 37.

Comment: Your border-box is messing the thing up. Is your border-box really of any use there ? Because your container's real height is not 47px + but 47-10(from borders) = 37 px. If you want to vertically center your text in a border-boxed input you have to  substract any padding or borders applyied to it.

Comment: Add to this that your font-size is 34pt which give 45px when converted to pixels. Since your container real height is 37px, your text can't even be contained in this input. You should : 1. give a higher height to your container 2. forget about border-boxes or 3. lower your font-size before searching any other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line-height matching your element's height. Be sure to match the height without padding. That's the best way to vertically center a single-line text in an element with known height

Also, make sure your font fits the height, if a height is already defined, as probably is the case with an input field

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the following but it doesn't work:
http://pastebin.com/5bpubPng

Comment: Your container is too small for the font-size. You either need a font-size of a maximum 26pt or an input of 47px height 47px line-height.

Comment: I see, thank you. So I guess if I wanted this to work, I would need to have 2 separate DOM elements with position:absolute that overlap, one being the text, and one being the border...